# centos: ping6 unknown host

Tags: centos, ping, ipv6

I have centos 6.5 with ipv6 enabled and working (partially).
When I'm trying to execute "ping6 bin6.it" it returns error "unknown host":

```
[root@centos ~]# ping6 bin6.it
unknown host
```

Host is resolvable:

```
[root@centos ~]# host bin6.it
bin6.it has IPv6 address 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11
bin6.it mail is handled by 20 mx02.puttynuts.com.
bin6.it mail is handled by 10 mx01.puttynuts.com.
```

Ping to ip address is working too:

```
[root@centos ~]# ping6 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11
PING 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11(2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=273 ms
64 bytes from 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=268 ms
64 bytes from 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=268 ms
64 bytes from 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=268 ms
--- 2607:fd50:1:91b0::b146:11 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4026ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 268.293/269.715/273.367/2.215 ms
```

What is wrong?

Added by requests:

```
[root@centos ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search mydomain.com
nameserver 192.168.5.34

[root@centos ~]# grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
#hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
#hosts:      dns files mdns4_minimal
hosts:      files dns mdns4
```

Answer (score 1):

`host` checks DNS directly, while `ping6` (and `ping`) resolve the name to an IP address via the Name Service Switch (NSS).

Check `/etc/nsswiitch.conf` and make sure you have `dns` on the `hosts:` entry, similar to the following:

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```